# Angular Table row dissapears after editing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm using *ng-repeat* in an table to dynamically generate contents. I have given an option to *edit* and *delete* the table contents.

But the issue I'm facing is that once I edit and save a row, It disappears. I tried manually adding value to table row using jQuery but still it did not work.

Here is the [Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/vishnuys/pen/PpqbdR) for my code.

**Here's my html page:**

```
 <div class="container" ng-app="trial">
   <table class="table table-hover" ng-controller="newTrial">
     <tr>
       <th class="col-md-3">Name</th>
       <th class="col-md-2">Age</th>
       <th class="col-md-5">Description</th>
       <th class="col-md-2">Actions</th>
     </tr>
     <tr ng-repeat="entry in entryList">
       <td ng-hide="edit[$index]">{{entry.name}}</td>
       <td ng-hide="edit[$index]">{{entry.age}}</td>
       <td ng-hide="edit[$index]">{{entry.desc}}</td>
       <td ng-hide="edit[$index]">
         <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editEntry($index)">Edit</button>
         <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteEntry($index)">Delete</button>
       </td>
       <td ng-show="edit[$index]">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-value="entry.name" id="nameEdit$index" />
       </td>
       <td ng-show="edit[$index]">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-value="entry.age" id="ageEdit$index" />
       </td>
       <td ng-show="edit[$index]">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-value="entry.desc" id="descEdit$index" />
       </td>
       <td ng-show="edit[$index]">
         <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="saveEntry($index)">Save</button>
         <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancelEntry($index)">Cancel</button>
       </td>
     </tr>

   </table>
 </div>
```

**Here's my javascript file:**

```
var app = angular.module('trial', []);

app.controller('newTrial', ["$scope", function($scope){
  $scope.edit = [false, false, false];
  $scope.entryList = [
    {
      name: "ABC",
      age: 30,
      desc: "Something he does"
    },
    {
      name: "DEF",
      age: 35,
      desc: "Something he does not do"
    },
    {
      name: "GHI",
      age: 32,
      desc: "Something he is good at"
    }
  ];
  $scope.editEntry = (i) => {
    $scope.edit[i] = true;
  };
  $scope.deleteEntry = (i) => {
    $scope.edit.splice( i , 1 );
    $scope.entryList.splice( i , 1 );
  };
  $scope.saveEntry = (i) => {
    $scope.entryList[i].name = angular.element("nameEdit"+i).val();
    $scope.entryList[i].age = angular.element("ageEdit"+i).val();
    $scope.entryList[i].desc = angular.element("descEdit"+i).val();
    $scope.edit[i] = false;
  };
  $scope.cancelEntry = (i) => {
    $scope.edit[i] = false;
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know why you write down show much code  you can do it simply as follow:-

```
 <tr ng-repeat="entry in entryList" >
       <td ng-if="!entry.isEditable">{{entry.name}}</td>
       <td ng-if="!entry.isEditable">{{entry.age}}</td>
       <td ng-if="!entry.isEditable">{{entry.desc}}</td>
       <td ng-if="!entry.isEditable">
         <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="entry.isEditable = !entry.isEditable">Edit</button>
         <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteEntry(entry)">Delete</button>
       </td>
        <td ng-if="entry.isEditable">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="entry.name"  />
       </td>
       <td ng-if="entry.isEditable">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="entry.age"  />
       </td>
       <td ng-if="entry.isEditable">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="entry.desc"  />
       </td>
       <td ng-if="entry.isEditable">
         <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="saveEntry(entry)">Save</button>
         <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="entry.isEditable = !entry.isEditable">Cancel</button>
       </td>

     </tr>
```

In you controller

```
 $scope.deleteEntry = (i) => {
    $scope.entryList.splice( i , 1 );
  };
  $scope.saveEntry = (entry) => {
    //do somthing here
 entry.isEditable = !entry.isEditable
  };
```

[Working pulker](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KWpaZp)

Comment: Thank you, that works. Can you let me my mistake in the code? And also isEditable is not defined anywhere. How does it still work? I'm curious to know.

Comment: Angular is all about two-way binding as so you don't need to use array[something] this seems more like javascipt instead of angular.Also i use isEditable just as a reference as isEditable is undef when we say isEditable= !isEditable it will auto set it to true.Also please mark this as accepted answer if it works for you

Comment: I was waiting for the comment reply to accept the answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: glad it helped you